# Is there an upper limit to the number of times a value can occur in a superset?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Given a set of numbers $S=\{-5,6,9,3,2,-2\}$, is there an upper limit to the number of times a particular value (say $4$) can occur in the sums of all the combinations of these numbers?

For example: in the above set $9-5 = 4$, $6-2 = 4$, $6+3-5 = 4$, etc. That's $3$ times the number $4$ shows up.  Is there an upper limit to the number times a value can show up.

Is there a way to calculate this?

Comment: What are *combinations of numbers*?

Comment: Oh...sorry...sums.  I'll edit.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Can, say $-5$, be used only once?

Comment: Yes, just once.

Comment: Then there is of course an upper limit to the number of times $s\in \mathbb N$ can occurr, due to the fact there is a finite number of sums: the sums of two elements $5\choose 2$, the sums of three elements $5\choose 3$, etc

Comment: I'll add more clarification.

Comment: @C Shreve my comment answers the question. I don't know how many times $4$ shows up, but I know the number of times it shows up is smaller (or equal to) than $\sum \limits_{k=0}^5\left(5\choose k\right)$, therefore this sum is an upper limit

Comment: That definitely is an upper limit: given a set of 5 numbers this means that 4 could show up as the sum 26 times(!).  Surely it must be smaller than this.

Comment: @C Shreve Yes, but you asked for an upper limit. Do you perhaps mean to ask for a 'good' estimate?

Comment: Lolz.  Git Gud - perhaps your right.  Would you know of any 'better estimate' than the sum of m choose n?